# undefined symbol for architecture x86_64 in compiling C program

Tags: c

I have a simple program as
**demo_use.c**

```
#include "libhello.h"

int main(void) {
 hello();
 return 0;
}
```

**libhello.h**

```
void hello(void);
```

**libhello.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(void) {
  printf("Hello, library world.\n");
}
```

I have used the command in terminal as

```
gcc demo_use.c -o test
```

**error** 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_hello",

referenced from: _main in ccZdSQP3.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Use: `gcc demo_use.c libhello.c -o test` , you need both files. Note that [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) is a better option for multiple files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to compile both the source files together to generate the binary. use

```
gcc demo_use.c libhello.c -o test
```

Otherwise, the definition of `hello()` function will be absent. So, at linking time, linker will throw `undefined symbol` error.